# how to Design the exported excel in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am exporting gridview data to excel but that excel file add the some lable text and textbox values and format also taken , pls give how to design the excel code in asp.net. I am writing like this

- All gridview data taken dataset ds
  -pls give me  textbox values and some label or normal text designed code in excel

  GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
          GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
          GridView1.DataSource = ds;
          GridView1.DataBind();

  ```
      Response.Clear();
      Response.Buffer = true;
      Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
      "attachment;filename=DataTable.xls");
      Response.Charset = string.Empty;
      Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
      StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
      HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

      for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
      ////Apply text style to each Row
              GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
      }
      GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

      //style to format numbers to string
      string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:'\#,\#\#0\.00';}
      .textmode1(mso-number-format:'\@';}
      .SSNmode{mso-number-format:'000-00-000';} </style>";


      Response.Write(style);
      Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
      Response.Flush();
      Response.End();
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this awesome tool: http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/

Futhermore, the author also created a code generator, which generates .net code from a provided excel sheet(formatting, layout and so on) 
http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/Generator.aspx

Here's some code that generates an excel file from a datatable (converted vb code, as pr. request by poster)

```
        CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.Workbook book = new CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.Workbook();
        book.ExcelWorkbook.ProtectWindows = false;

        book.ExcelWorkbook.ProtectStructure = false;

        var styles = book.Styles;
        WorksheetStyle defaultStyle = styles.Add("Default");
        var defStyles = defaultStyle;
        defStyles.Name = "Normal";
        defStyles.Font.FontName = "Calibri";
        defStyles.Font.Size = 11;
        defStyles.Font.Color = "#000000";
        defStyles.Alignment.Vertical = StyleVerticalAlignment.Bottom;

        Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        sheet.Table.DefaultRowHeight = 15f;
        sheet.Table.FullColumns = 1;
        sheet.Table.FullRows = 1;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();  //=  your datatable

        //Header
        WorksheetRow HeaderRow = sheet.Table.Rows.Add();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            HeaderRow.Cells.Add(col.ColumnName.ToString());

        }
        //Body
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            WorksheetRow row = sheet.Table.Rows.Add();
            foreach (DataColumn cols in dt.Columns)
            {
                  row.Cells.Add(dr[cols.ColumnName.ToString()].ToString());
            }
        }

        sheet.Options.Selected = true;
        sheet.Options.ProtectObjects = false;
        sheet.Options.ProtectScenarios = false;

        book.Save("path to file");
```

Comment: Hi, i don't do c# - you can use this site to convert: http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx

Comment: but convertion is not working in ur code error like this -- line 1 col 1: EOF expected

Comment: I think i am being a little too nice here, but i edited the post. Sometimes you have to mingle the code a little when converting.